# Could not open include file<.hpp>

Tags: c++

i am using sunOS cc compiler to run my unittest.cpp file but it is creating problem while including header files as they are written using <> angle brackets (i know local dir header path to be given as "")and even inside header files the other header files are called by using <>(angle brackets) so, it is giving "couldn't include file" error

```
EVIMPT_Sprint26/GeoPlugins/AtlasSegmentationPlugin/AbsEngine/Image_unittest.cc /home/saravind/work/gtest/gtest-1.5.0/scripts/test/output/gtest/gtest.h
"/home/saravind/work/Pinnacle_DEVIMPT_Sprint26/GeoPlugins/AtlasSegmentationPlugin/AbsEngine/prima/image/volume.hpp", line 31: Error: Could not open include file<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>.
```

and i cannot change <> to "" for all header files it is taking in !!

here is my sample unittest file

```
#include <AutoSegTask.hpp>
#include <AutoSegTaskDetails.hpp>
using namespace std;
class Autosegmentationunittest
{
using namespace autoSegmentation;

Image img;
cout<<"hi";
}


<AutoSegTask.hpp> intakes other header files included using <>
```

Comment: You *do* have Boost installed? In a system directory that the preprocessor searches automatically?

Comment: yes boost is installed and boost directory resides at the right location as in the program.